# Power outlet power goes out when plugged in device is moved

Tags: electrical

Have PC connect to outlet and whenever the stove is turn on the rgb keyboard lights up when the stove sparking to turn on burner. What I notice is that when I apply torque to the divice plug to the outlet by moving the cable the outlet looses power. Only happens in bottom outlet.

Comment: Looks like two separate problems. Sparking stove may be causing RF interference. Plug outage is probably a loose/worn outlet or a defective power cord.

Comment: replace the receptacle, they only cost a buck or two.

Comment: I take it this is a gas range? Are the two devices on the same circuit, or on different circuits?